# skip ending rows containing string while reading a txt file with numpy to generate a numerical array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to generate an array reading a text file from internet.

My target is to use Python instead of MATLAB, to replace this step in MATLAB:

```
url=['http://www.cdc.noaa.gov/Correlation/amon.us.long.data'];
urlwrite(url,'file.txt');
```

I'm using this code:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.cdc.noaa.gov/Correlation/amon.us.long.data', '/Users/epy/file2.txt')
a = np.loadtxt('/Users/epy/file2.txt', skiprows=1, dtype=None)
```

But it fails because of the text description at the end of the file.

Do you know if exist a way to skip the X lines at the end, or I have to use some sort of string manipulation (readlines?) instead?

Answer (score 11):

For more complex text loading, have a look at [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

It's slower than `numpy.loadtxt` but more flexible.

In your case (I'm avoiding saving a temporary file here...):

```
import numpy as np
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.cdc.noaa.gov/Correlation/amon.us.long.data'
data = np.genfromtxt(urllib2.urlopen(url), skip_header=1, skip_footer=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

for who ever come here thoes days, its alot easier(np.loadtxt can also get generator):

instead of

```
a = np.loadtxt('/Users/epy/file2.txt', skiprows=1, dtype=None)
```

just write

```
a = np.loadtxt(open('/Users/epy/file2.txt','rt').readlines()[:-1]), skiprows=1, dtype=None)
```

will also skip last line

Comment: is this faster than `np.genfromtxt` ?

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a comment answering riddleculous's comment. But I haven't earned the privilege.

As per today, using jack onsl's solution with

> a = np.loadtxt(open(file,'rt').readlines()[:-1], skiprows=1, dtype=None)

is about 30% faster than using `np.genfromtext`

Using 137 files with around 500 lines in each.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out a typo in [@jack onsl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51760241/7057632) answer.
Removing one superfluous parentheses after `[:-1]`  yields:

```
a = np.loadtxt(open('/Users/epy/file2.txt','rt').readlines()[:-1], skiprows=1, dtype=None)
```

Otherwise, I can confirm that this works in numpy version 1.21.5.